# How is there monotone operators on Banach spaces whilst there is no inner production?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, inner-products, semigroup-of-operators, monotone-operator-theory

While studying some books on Semigroups theory, I always get that monotone operators are defined on Hilbert spaces and my professor always warn us that we can't define such an operator in a banach space since we don't have the inner product. However, I came across this definition quite often and it really throws me off:

> The operator $A:X \to X^*$ is monotone on the reflexive Banach space $X$ if:
> $\langle Ax - Ay, x-y\rangle \geq 0$ for all $x,y \in X$.

How is it possible to define inner product in a Banach space?

Comment: I assume you mean $x,y \in X$ instead of $u,v$. in the Banach space setting one often writes $\langle y,x \rangle$ and means $y(x)$ for $y \in X^*$ and $x \in X$

Comment: This is common in algebra as well, in particular when the pairing is perfect, i.e. "reflexive".

Comment: To amplify @Targon's comment: What you wrote as $\langle Ax-Ay,x-y\rangle$ is not an inner product in $X$ but the standard pairing between $X^*$ and $X$.  And this definition is not about operators on $X$ but transformations $X\to X^*$.